# How to save the userID in the login cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

Using manual login to a web application,

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(_username, true);
```

How can I save the userID (an integer value) with its cookie ?

Answer (score 3):

**FormsAuthenticationTicket** has an overload which takes `string userData`. This is where you can add additional data into the encrypted cookie you need to persist in addition to the default `HttpContext.User.Identity` (which is usually the email address, e.g what is signed in with `SetAuthCookie`).

So you could do this:

```
    var user = new User { UserId = 1, Nickname = "Foo" };

    var encodedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(
       new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
          1, 
          user.Nickname, 
          DateTime.Now,  
          DateTime.UtcNow.Add(FormsAuthentication.Timeout),
          true,                                                                            
          user.ToString()));

var httpCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encodedTicket);
httpResponseBase.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
```

You could ovveride the `ToString()` method on your `User` object to persist that info (as a delimited string, for example).

Then when you decrypt the cookie, split the string and pull back the info you need on each request.

Comment: Thank you. People do not read comments often. This is a better way to make them able to see your point and benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fay1e4k.aspx)

```
HttpCookie httpCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(_username, true); 
httpCookie["ID"] = userID.ToString();
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? He's asking how to save it as part of the forms auth ticket, not to pull it back.

Comment: He wrotes "manual login". I guess that means he's filexible about what he wants.. Please provide other solutions if you have. If I had other solutions my self I will provide them as well.

Answer (score 0):

User Name used in authentication scheme does not necessarily mean the login name or actual person name for the user. It essentially means any string that can identify your user - so typically, login name would be used in case of forms authentication (as login would be unique) but you may user user id instead (or combination of login & user id e.g. "2|jack") - just remember whatever value you use as "user name", the same will be available as user's identity (`HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`).